# Delay 2 seconds to delete an item

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I have a listview with checkboxes enabled. 
When a user checks an item I need to remove this item after two seconds, without locking the screen.

How I can do it? Do I need to use a thread?

Comment: add timer and OnTick event remove checked item, no thread required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `Timer` to perform some operation after a given amount of time.  Because this is performing the operation asynchronously, rather than synchronously, the UI thread won't be blocked.

The other option is to leverage `await`:

```
private async void checkbox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (checkbox.Checked)
    {
        await Task.Delay(2000);
        RemoveItem();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a [`Timer` control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) from the `System.Windows.Forms` namespace.

That will trigger an event in the main thread when the time has elapsed, so you won't have any issues to try to access the form from a different thread.